# When I upload package,an error occurred :"upload failed" all the time

Tags: appgallery

I am not using any vpn, proxy settings are appropriate and is not company network. There is no problem in my application. I have tried with different computers and different internet network, but again I encountered this problem. I can not publish my application. Despite the fact that my information, files and settings are very neat, I am constantly facing the problem. [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please kindly find the update from related team.

Experts has done some investigation according to the log.

1. Please kindly check whether the internal network or proxy is used. If yes, switch to the external network, for example, mobile phone hotspot.
2. Please kindly check whether the host is configured.
3. If the preceding two possibilities are excluded, please kindly confirm if you are willing to remotely view the video. If so, we will arrange a welink meeting and send the meeting link to your email address. You can click the link in the email to remotely view the video.

Thanks for the support.